# Tomcat: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I deploy Java project to Tomcat 7.0.56 server. 
It's an HTML-document with some links to another HTML-pages. So main page of it displayed normally but when I push on any link I get a message:

```
type: Status report
message: /chooseReport
description: The requested resource is not available.
```

I'm new with that and don't know why Tomcat can't display other pages.

UPD: Some code from main page:

```
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "col">
             <a href="/chooseReport"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, will you please provide some code for the HTML-pages?  It will be hard to determine the location of your error without any specific examples.  Thanks!

Comment: @abalos Thank you for reply:) I can't send all code but I can explain that in <body> tag I have <div> tag and in that tag I have <a href="/chooseReport></a> for example. Something like in the UPD

Comment: @fr0st I'm really sure it's not about the HTML, but webApp misconfiguration. Where do You get that message (logs?) ?

Comment: Do you have the URL /chooseReport handled by a servlet or mapping anywhere?  It would make sense that Tomcat is throwing this error if you don't tell it where /chooseReport is supposed to go.

Comment: @maslan Thank you for reply too:) I get this message on Tomcat server after I deploying my project on http://localhost:8085/java_web (java_web is the name of my application)

Comment: does this link work:  `<a href="./chooseReport"></a>` ?

Comment: @طاهر Thanks for reply but this doesn't work for me:C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are JSPs you need to specify your href as

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resource">Link to Some Resource</a>
```

If you just specify "/" you are telling the browser to go to the root of the container which may not be the same as the location of your webapp.

Comment: Thanks a lot:)) This is the solution of my problem:)))

Comment: Glad I could help - been burned by it enough times to know exactly what you're going through.